# Simple $RC$ circuits

Tags: electric-circuits, charge, electrical-resistance, capacitance, batteries

I have a $RC$ circuit with a capacitor (capacitance$=C$) uncharged initially and resistor (resistance$=R$) in series with the battery of EMF $E$. Assume its internal resistance to be negligible.
Now this circuit has time varying current and an analysis of its transient state was done by applying Kirchoff's voltage law and ohm's law
and then the equation was $q/c+iR=E$ (considering potential drops and rises)
Now my question is how can one use $C=Q/V$ for such a transient system.The derivation of the fact that the ratio $Q/V$ is constant is done using uniqueness theorem of electrostatics. hence   it appeals to me that this equation can be used only when steady state will be reached (current=0) and hence it will be an electrostatic system.

Answer (score 0):

Whether the formula $Q=CV$ is a *useful* one or not depends on the *shortest* rise/fall time, say $\tau$ of the transient and on the dominant length size, say $\ell$, of the capacitor. Specifically, if $\frac{\ell}{\tau} \ll c$ then $Q=VC$ is applicable, if not then it will be inaccurate or even completely wrong. When inaccurate it may be fixable by a more complicated model of the capacitor that may involve some other inductive or capacitive terms. When completely wrong then the capacitor may become a lousy antenna and radiates too.